# How do I select/edit a range of cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to edit/select a range of cells.

The cell addresses rely on which cell/s I choose then run a simple script to add 1.

Basically, highlight a range of cells (or 1 cell), then edit all of those at the same time.

Comment: It's going to be difficult for anyone to help without seeing your code. Can you [edit it into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52894575/edit)?

Comment: This site is more for fixing broken code than writing it from scratch. Have you tried writing anything yourself? If so, share it with us and tell us what's failing and you'll likely get an answer. If you haven't, check out / google `For Each cell in Selection` examples to get going.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *range of active cells*. Only one cell can be the `activeCell`

Comment: i'm new to coding and have been trying to read up on it. 

so from your answers, it seems like i would need to plug it in a loop that goes through every cell selected and do the arithmetic separately..thanks for your answers.

Answer (score -1):

This solution only works to set the same value to all the cells:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C3").Value = "your value"
```

If you really want to  highlight a range of cells:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C3").Select
```

But if you try to edit the selection only the first cell will have its value changed.

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that "if you try to edit the selection only the first cell will have its value changed"?  `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C3").Select: Selection.Value = "x"` assigns exactly like your first snippet.